# Create HttpClient for multiple requests but different users

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I need some assistance working with .Net5 HttpClient. I am currently building a middle man API so our users can perform actions on a third party vendor API, but we cannot grant them full access to this 3rd API.

**The problem to solve:** My user's setup is an Angular SPA where users can perform a single action and this will trigger several endpoints from this third party vendor.
As an example:
My user could create a project in the vendor API. The following are the steps to do this:

1. We need to do a POST to createProject
2. Then a PUT to add users to the project
3. PUT to configure permissions and access levels
4. ...
5. If any of the above fails, Call the DELETE project and notify my user something went wrong.

Therefore I believed the best way to do was to wrap all this in a single API that will take care of all the steps, validation etc...

The way this vendor works is that the first call I need to make to its API is to the /login endpoint. The call will respond with a token in the header, and a Set-cookie with the session id. In the consecutive calls I need to send this token as part of the header and keep the cookie in the context while I keep doing calls.

**The challenge**: according to the documentation for the HttpClientHandler, the cookie context will be reused for all the requests that go through the system.

- Does this mean that if two users send a request to my API at the same time, would they be sharing the same sessionId/Token with the third party vendor?

I could find some posts in stackoverflow mentioning about a workaround when creating the HttpClient which would disable the automatic cookie handler but then I would have to parse the response from the /Login call and generate a new HttpClient with these new values? Would this count as persisting the context for this call and not destroy the headers and credentials sent originally for each user?

Sorry if this question has been answered before. I just got confused on how this is a bit too complicated. My previous experience with a similar case was Python, and in this language you can create a Session object that will only be kept for the lifetime of the request, won't share any details with other requests and will keep the context intact. Is it possible to achieve the same result with Net5?

**TLDR/Summary?:** On an ApiController, after receiving an outside request, how can I create and reuse the same HttpClient to do multiple HTTP requests using the same cookies without sharing cookies with any other future incoming requests.
I hope the TLDR doesn't make this more confusing.

Comment: You can register services into the DI with scoped lifetime, that way one service will be used for one incoming http request, similarly to what you wrote about python session objects. You can read more about DI in ASP.NET Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Would this work for the HttpClientFactory or HttpClientHandlers? According to the documentation, the handlers are created on a pool and shared for all incoming requests. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0